# Redmine Custom Calculated Fields

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins, calculated-field

Using Redmine v3.3, is it possible to have a custom calculated field based on data in two other custom fields?

e.g. Duration = Date 2 - Date 1

Specifically, I am attempting to calculate the days between two dates as a performance metric. More generally, we will be looking to eventually using other custom calculated fields (simple additions, multiplications, etc.).

It would be preferable to keep this to the "vanilla" Redmine v3.3 without additional plugins but all suggestions are of course welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in Vanilla Redmine as of 3.3, unfortunately.

It has been requested and there was some discussion about it. The feature wasn't rejected but nobody has gotten around to building it for Redmine. You can follow the discussion/development here:

http://www.redmine.org/issues/1712

A plugin is discussed in that issue as well but - as with all plugins - a thorough check will be required if it matches your stability/security expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Such [feature request](https://www.redmine.org/issues/1712) has been filed 11 years ago (2008-7-30), while not yet enhanced.

---

At the moment, you can try [**Computed Custom Field**](https://www.redmine.org/plugins/computed_custom_field) plugin.

Although it shows "This project is no longer maintained", it stated that it is comptatible with latest stable version of Redmine 4.0.4 (2019-06-10).

> Current version: 1.0.7 (2019-01-14)
>   Compatible with: Redmine 4.0.x, 3.4.x, 3.3.x, 3.2.x, 3.1.x, 3.0.x, 2.6.x, 2.5.x